# Cheerio and css selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cheerio

Hi I'm trying to make a selector to select the number 332 from

```
<div data-stat="PVPMatchesWon" class="trn-defstat__value">
332
</div>
```

But I don't know how to do it... I'm trying with Cheerio and Jquery but it doesn't work ...

```
let wins = $(`div.trn-defstat--large:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)`).text()
```

`( div.trn-defstat--large:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) )` this is the css selector.

I know my question is easy for some but I am stuck.

Comment: You should try to use `:nth-child(1)` with a colon at the begginnig. `div.trn-defstat--large:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)`

Comment: I tryed it too but it's the same... it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just:

```
$('[data-stat="PVPMatchesWon"]').text()
```

I doubt there's another one of those.